# Create a VisualWebPart from Picture Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-web-part

I've a Picture Library to which I added pictures,now i want to create a Visual Web Part which displays a list of pictures added to library like this

[image]

I created the similar design in ascx file like this

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">
                <img src='<%#Eval("Image") %>' alt="" /></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Title") %>'></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I am not getting what should i write in src field of image to display thumbnails.

Here I wrote `'<%#Eval("Image") %>'` in code for explanation purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use code like this to get image url:

```
SPList spList = web.Lists["ImagesLibrary"];
SPListItem item = spList.Items.GetItemById(itemID);

//Thumbnail Url
string thumbnailUrl = item[SPBuiltInFieldId.EncodedAbsThumbnailUrl].ToString();

//Picture Url
string pictureUrl = item[SPBuiltInFieldId.EncodedAbsUrl].ToString();
```

The above Urls are the full Urls of the thumbnail and picture respectively.
To get the absolute, relative Urls of the picture the Url can be managed as below.

```
Uri uri = new Uri(thumbnailUrl);

string relativePath = uri.AbsolutePath;
```

[link](http://sharepointcore.blogspot.com/2011/03/sharepoint-picturelibrary-thumbnail-url.html) to source

Comment: Thanx it works fine :)